# Using functions to create a new list in PYTHON

Tags: python, function

I have a list of 30 integers (GRADES[30]) from 0-100.I need to create a new list of 30 integers (NEW[30]) in a function, that has the same integers of GRADES[30] + 3 except those that have the value of 97(because it would exceed 0-100).Can someone help me on how to do it?For example if GRADES[5]=57, NEW[5] must be 60.

Comment: `new_grades = [g + 3 for g in GRADES if g <= 97]`

Comment: "except those that have the value of 97" ? Unclear. How to do with 97, how to do with greater than 97 ?

Comment: @StephenRauch why not make this an answer?

Comment: if for example GRADES[15]=98,  NEW[15] should stay =98

Comment: @ΝίκοςΒαλτσιόγης Then 96->99, 98->98 ? It sounds not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that like:

#### Code:

To drop grades > 97:

```
new_grades = [g + 3 for g in GRADES if g <= 97]
```

To clip grades to 100:

```
new_grades = [min(100, g + 3) for g in GRADES]
```

Comment: `min(100, g + 3)`??

Comment: `[g + (3 if g <= 97 else 0) for g in GRADES]`

Comment: `scalar = (0, 3);   b = [g + scalar[g <= 97] for g in GRADES]`

Answer (score 0):

This is an in place solution. If your list is not a `numpy` array you can convert it to one using `x = np.array(lst)`.

```
import numpy as np

x[np.where(x <= 97)] += 3
```